# Meteorjs handle scraped data from server to client returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-scraping, meteor

I am trying to achieve a url preview for my Meteor + React app, where when users paste in a url in a textarea, they'll get a preview of the url. I plan to achieve this by using several npm modules i.e.:

1. [url-regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-regex), and
2. [open-graph-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-graph-scraper)

I understand that in order to avoid any CORS issue, the request should be done server side.
So I have this currently set up:

//on client

```
import urlRegex from 'url-regex';
const onTextareaChange = e => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    let testURL = urlRegex().test(value) //returns true if url exists in textarea
    console.log(testURL);
    if(testURL){
        let extractURL = value.match(urlRegex()) //extract the url
        extractURL.map(url =>{
            console.log(url)
            Meteor.call('scrapeURL',{url}, function (result){
                 console.log(result)         
            })

        })
    }
    /* console.log(e.target.value) */
    setTextarea(e.target.value)
 }
```

//on server

```
import ogs from 'open-graph-scraper';
/* 24. scrapeURL */
'scrapeURL' ({url}){
  new SimpleSchema({
    url : { type  : String }
  }).validate({url})
  if(!Meteor.userId){
    throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorised!')
  } else {
    let options = { 'url': url };
      ogs(options)
        .then(function (result) {
          console.log('result:', result);
          return result;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('error:', error);
        });
  }
}
```

The problem here is, when i tried to `console.log` the `results` on the server, the scraped data shows up in the server console. but when i tried to return the `results` from the server to client, `console.log` on the client shows `undefined`.

I haven't got a clue what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scrapeUrl function doesn't return any data (you only described what the `.then()` function will return), you should try this way :

```
import ogs from 'open-graph-scraper';
/* 24. scrapeURL */
'scrapeURL' ({url}){
  new SimpleSchema({
    url : { type  : String }
  }).validate({url})
  if(!Meteor.userId){
    throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorised!')
  } else {
    let options = { 'url': url };

    // here return the full promise : 
    return ogs(options)
        .then(function (result) {
          console.log('result:', result);
          return result;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('error:', error);
          // probably here a need to tell the client that there was an error
          //throw new Meteor.Error(error);
        });
  }
}
```

Here is a good reading on medium about the use of promises in Meteor : 
https://blog.meteor.com/using-promises-and-async-await-in-meteor-8f6f4a04f998